# How does the Biden Administration intend to keep humanitarian aid to Gaza out of the hands of Hamas?

Tags: united-states, joe-biden, gaza, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

President Biden announced that he was sending aid to the Gaza strip, and [warned Hamas against taking said aid](https://thehill.com/policy/international/4266108-biden-warns-hamas-against-blocking-aid-deliveries-to-palestinian-civilians/)

> President Biden on Thursday warned Hamas against diverting
> humanitarian shipments to the Gaza Strip, saying its sustained
> delivery was dependent on goods reaching Palestinian civilians.
>
> “If Hamas does not divert or steal these shipments, we’re going to
> provide an opening for sustained delivery of lifesaving humanitarian
> assistance for the Palestinians,” the president said in a rare
> prime-time address.

Has President Biden indicated how he intends to ensure Hamas does not divert these supplies?

Comment: The threat is that if Hamas diverts them, the aid will end. Although realistically, it probably can't end without mass starvation. Unless Israel manages to take full control of the territory fast that is, and be in charge directly of the population (which however they don't seem to be keen to do--meaning the latter). Not my DV, by the way.

Comment: Is it even possible?

Comment: "Don’t underestimate Joe’s ability to f–k things up,” - Barack Obama. Without boots on the ground that have access to monitor the supplies, audit reports, and verify claims, the only real option he has is trusting Hamas. There is no official US presence in Gaza. This leaves intelligence gathering to supplement what Hamas tells us.

Comment: For now the US says their threats are working https://www.aa.com.tr/en/middle-east/no-evidence-of-hamas-seizing-aid-entering-gaza-us-envoy-/3043719 And they seem to fly their own drones, BTW. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-67317218

Comment: OTOH the Israeli position appears to changing "Israeli PM Benjamin Netanyahu said Israel will have “overall security responsibility” for the Gaza Strip for “an indefinite period” once the fighting is over, in an interview with US channel ABC News."